# Converting MM:SS.ms to seconds using MS excel

Tags: excel, time, string-formatting, data-conversion, seconds

I am looking for a neat way of converting a cell from

`Minutes:Seconds.Milliseconds` to

`Seconds.Milliseconds`

i.e.

```
11.111    = 11.111
1:11.111  = 71.111
```

I have something in place at the moment but its a bit hacky and I am sure there must be some nice excel feature to do this for me :P

Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

Do this:

Place values `0:0:11.111` and `0:1:11.111` in cells `B3` and `B4` respectively.

Now format it to account for the milliseconds... Select cells `B3` and `B4`, right click and choose Format Cells. In Custom, put the following in the text box labeled `Type`:

```
[h]:mm:ss.000
```

Now on cell `C3` put the following formula:

```
=B3*86400
```

Fill `C4` with the same formula...

Format column `C` as `Number` with 3 decimal places.

You're done! :)

Here's a screenshot of the attempt I made and that worked:

[image]

**Edit:**

As you wanna enter only `MM:SS.ms` you can format the entire `B` column with a custom format like: `mm:ss.000`. Now you can enter values as `02:11.111` and it'll convert it accordingly giving you `131.110`. Hope it helps.

Comment: This works great if the number is fully qualified. i.e. 0:00.11.111, but when the number is simply entered as 11:111 it gives the wrong answer.

Comment: You're not entering it in the expected format. It should be: `11.111` and not `11:111`.

Comment: Hello Leniel, re your edit at the end, surely if column is formatted as mm:ss.000 and you enter 02:11.111 you will still see exactly that, to see 131.111 you need a custom format of `[s].000`

Comment: @barryhoudini this is not necessary here since Column `C` has a formula in place to do the conversion and display the correct values.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I missed the point......you could use that custom format in any case to display the current value differently, as with formula suggestion 11.111 would need to be entered as 0:11.111

Answer (score 3):

say your time is in cell `A1`, place this formula in `B1`

```
=IF(LEN(A1)>5,VALUE(TEXT(A1,"[ss].00")),A1)
```

If the time is less than a minute it outputs the time unaltered, greater than 1 minute it converts it to seconds & milliseconds (2 decimal places).

This will only work if your time in `A1` is 10 seconds or greater.