# How to convert " 'n' min 'm' secs" to seconds format

Tags: excel, datetime, formatting, excel-formula

I have received an Excel sheet with format time: `1 min 30 secs`.

How do I convert the field with string and integer format to numeric format like 90 in order to perform average?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11416779/converting-mmss-ms-to-seconds-using-ms-excel).

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1))*60+SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,3,LEN(A1)),"min ","")," secs","")
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this:

```
=TEXT("0:"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," min ",":")," sec",""),"[s]")
```

Comment: Why are ppl always downvoting without leaving an understandable reason? -.-

Comment: I slowly get used to it. Just a lilbit more and i won't ask anymore :P